# Equation of motion given by $\ddot x = -\mbox{sgn}(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following differential equation

$$\ddot x = -\mbox{sgn}(x)$$

where $x \mapsto \mbox{sgn} (x)$ is the sign function.

I can see that it would behave like constant acceleration but it also flips and oscillates when it crosses the origin.

Comment: Take a look at the [rocket car](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~loew/m403/rocketcar.pdf).

Comment: Derivatives must send intervals to intervals (Darboux), therefore strictly speaking a solution to this differential equation can only exist in an interval where its second derivative is constant (i.e. in the largest interval around $t_0$ where $x$ has the same sign as $x(t_0)$). With this in mind, the solutions to the initial condition $(t_0,x_0,x'_0)$ (by which I mean $x(t_0)=x_0$, $x'(t_0)=x'_0$) and their domains can be computed explicitly. The only solution to states $(t_0,0,0)$ is the constant $0$, and there aren't solutions to $(t_0,0,x'_0)$ when $x_0'\ne 0$.

Comment: On the other hand, if you mean $x$ to be a $C^1$ function such that $x''=-\operatorname{sgn}x$ whenever $x\ne0$, then we probably have a situation along the lines of your expectations.

Comment: One can integrate once after multiplying with $2x'$ to get $(x')^2+2|x|=C$. This implies closed bounded trajectories and thus a periodic solution.

Comment: Take a look at section 2.2 of [Slotine & Li](https://lewisgroup.uta.edu/ee5323/notes/Slotine%20and%20Li%20applied%20nonlinear%20control-%20bad%20quality.pdf) [PDF]

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and especially to @RodrigodeAzevedo for the very interesting PDFs. I quite liked the rocket car example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that the object crosses $x = 0$ at $t=0$ and enters the region $x > 0$ with a speed $v$ and experiencing a constant (negative) acceleration $-a$. Then the solution for the motion of the object is:

$$x(t) = vt - \frac{1}{2} at^2$$

$$v(t) = v - at$$

$$a(t) = -a$$

The object will reach a maximum distance $x_{max} = \frac{1}{2}v^2/a$, then it reverses its path and after a time $\tau = 2v/a$ it returns at the origin. Then it moves into the region $x <0$. Here the motion of the object is given by:

$$x(t) = -v(t-\tau) + \frac{1}{2}a(t-\tau)^2$$

$$v(t) = -v + a(t-\tau)$$

$$a(t) = a$$

After another time $\tau$ it returns to the origin. Then the whole cycle, with period $T = 2\tau$, repeats. In conclusion: the motion of the object is oscillatory around the origin, but the function describing its position is not sinusoidal but piecewise parabolic. The amplitude is $\frac{1}{2}v^2/a$ and the period is $T=2\tau = 4v/a$.

Comment: I will accept this "the function describing its position is not sinusoidal but piecewise parabolic" as the answer. I suppose I was looking for a single line function, I suppose some sort of periodic sinusoidal function, but it seems not to be possible from the other comments people left me. A piecewise parabolic function is still acceptable by all means, thank you!